# Qt / CPP: how to implement callbacks with signals and slots the "right way"

Tags: c++, qt, callback, signals, slot

I'm trying to implement an application in Qt with a model-view-controller scheme. I have some model classes (databases), one application controller, and a bunch of GUI classes. All GUI classes know the app controller and can call its public slots to send data to it that should be stored in the model. The app controller takes the data and calls the appropriate database to store it. The database classes check the data and return a bool to the app controller to tell if the data was okay or not.

Now, one GUI element has prepared some user data and wants to send it to the app controller. I am trying to figure out how to let the GUI-class know that the app controller validated the incoming data with the model and it accepted the data. My app controller shouldn't care nor know which GUI elements call its public API to commit data to the model. But how does the app controller communicate a response to the GUI element to tell it, that everything was fine, so the GUI element can close itself?

My idea would have been to let the GUI element create a random number token to send it to the app controller together with the data as a kind of "callback address". As soon as my GUI element receives an okay signal with the correct token attached, it can react to that.
I was dunno. All my solutions feel weird and not how it's supposed to be in Qt.

**Edit 1: a pseudo-code example for clarification:**

```
void Appcontroller::Slot(userdata)
{
    bool okay = database->save(userdata)
};

void Appcontroller::CreateMasterWindow()
{
    this->masterwindow_ = new MasterWindow(this);
    // I am propagating the knowledge of the app controller to the
    // MasterWindow and the latter can propagate that info further
    // down, that's fine (everybody can know the responsible
    // controller, but I don't think the controller should care about 
    // all his bastard children) 
};

void MasterWindow::CreateSubWindow()
{
    this->subwindow_ = new SubWindow(appcontroller_);
    // the masterwindow creates a random subwindow that the controller
    // should't have to care about
};

void SubWindow::SendUserData(userdata)
{
    QObject::connect(this, &SubWindow::SendToControllerSignal,
                     appcontroller_, &Appcontroller::Slot);
    emit SendToControllerSignal(userdata); 
    // how to get a callback (targeted to me/this) from this, 
    // if the appcontroller does not know me? what is de way?
};
```

Comment: please state your question in a crips manner. no-one has patience to read your essay

Comment: Re. `"My appcontroller shouldn't care nor know which GUI-elements call its public API to commit data to the model"`: one of the nice things about the signal/slot model (whether it be `Qt`, `boost` or whatever) is that neither the signaler nor the receiver need know anything about each other -- the connection between the two can be fixed up by some 'third party' code that has the required knowledge as to who should signal what to who and when.  Without seeing your code, however, all anyone can really do is guess as to the solution in your particular case.

Comment: @G.M. Well is that true though? I still need to connect(this, signal, appcontroller, slot). So at least my GUI-element has to know about the appcontroller and his slots (which is fine), right? If an anonymous callback from the appcontroller were possible it'd not be what I want, because I can potentially have a bunch of instances of the GUI-class and only the one sending the data should react to the "ok-signal". Not sure if my mock code would provide any more insight into the problem, because I think it's very general, but I'll write something down, if that helps you.

Comment: You missed this part of the comment: ***the connection between the two can be fixed up by some 'third party' code that has the required knowledge as to who should signal what to who and when***

Comment: @drescherjm: I didn't miss it. That would naturally be the job of my appcontroller. But as stated in my OP, I don't think it should be the responsibility of the appcontroller to know each and every GUI-element, that is spawned out of the GUI-elements it itself creates, you know? Of course I could implement all that, but that would be a potentially huge amount of boiler plate code. I am looking for an alternative, so ANY GUI-element can call the public API of the appcontroller and commit data and recieve a targeted response back.

Comment: @drescherjm sorry, I have added some pseudo-code to the OP to visualize it better.

Comment: @guttural Something needs to have knowledge of every GUI element - otherwise you have no application at all. The individual elements don't need to know. You can have a setup element that instantiates everything and connects it together, sure. Then the controller only reacts to things that the data model objects and the gui objects themselves can't deal with. It'd be connected to the others via signals and slots only. The composition of objects can be factored out into QML (yes, you can use QML to instantiate widgets and non-gui objects!). That's a perfect QML use case in fact!

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica: yeah, maybe that is the answer/concept I was searching for and my mental model was just wrong. And I'm glad I asked you guys and you provided a nice answer below. I will have to think about this and model my app differently I think. I think the basic CPP code is easy to understand as a beginner, but the architecture stuff is the really hard stuff. Glad you helped, so thanks mate!

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: **Connections should be made outside of the components. To compose the parts of your system, you instantiate the objects, and then connect them for desired functionality. The objects should otherwise have no knowledge of each other.**

Thus, the only means of communication between the objects are signals and slots.

> All GUI classes know the app controller and can call its public slots to send data to it that should be stored in the model

**Nope**.

The GUI classes should know nothing. When a GUI class needs something, it emits a signal. When a GUI class is supposed act on something (e.g. a change in the model), it exposes that as a slot.

> I am propagating the knowledge of the app controller to the MasterWindow

Why? The `MasterWindow` exposes its functionality via signals and slots. Composing it into a bigger system is accomplished by signal/slot connections. No other knowledge is needed.

> The app controller takes the data and calls the appropriate database to store it.

Does there even need to be a controller? All it seems to do is act like a signal-slot connection. You can directly connect the GUI classes to the database, and the controller could be what sets the connections up initially.

Otherwise, the application controller can act as a viewmodel, i.e. a `QAbstractItemModel` that *adapts* the model exposed by the database, and tweaks it for display/interaction (e.g. adds color properties, icons, etc.).

> The database classes check the data and return a bool to the app controller to tell if the data was okay or not.

The database classes should expose slots that are used to modify the database state. They should also expose signals that indicate any changes. To indicate failure, the database can indicate a "change" with the same value.

> how to get a callback (targeted to me/this) from this, if the appcontroller does not know me? what is de way?

The signals from the model/database are connected to the GUI classes. A GUI class can go into a "change pending" state once it emits a "change requested" signal. It will then react accordingly when its "new value" slot is called with the updated value: if the value didn't change, it indicates a failure, otherwise it indicates success. If it didn't request a change, it simply updates the displayed value - something else changed it.

This can be all done using nothing more than the `Q_PROPERTY` mechanism, and the change notification signals.

If the values aren't simple discretes, but rather have some structure, expose those as indices in a custom `QAbstractItemModel`. Each GUI item can then act on one or more model indices: requesting the changes, and reacting to value updates.

Multiple GUI elements can be hooked up to the same database variable (or no GUI elements!), and the GUI must support this and update its state to reflect the state of the model.

The "tickets" or "request identifiers" you propose are mostly spurious. The requesting GUI element has enough state to know that it requested a change, and can always act predictably on subsequent feedback from the model/database.

Comment: Thanks so much for your detailed response. I fear I have to go through this step by step and think about it, becaue I'm still a noob in CPP/Qt. Thank you for the input!

Comment: Think of signal-slot connections as wires, and think of objects like functional blocks you wire together. For example, when you use a timer module in industrial applications, the timer has no knowledge of what exactly it's used for. It's just a timer. Or, an indicator lamp - doesn't need to know what it's used for, just that it needs to turn on and off when told. A switch - same thing. The wiring establishes system-level behavior. The devices (widgets/objects) are ideally self-contained. Decoupling: it's mostly a good thing :)